# Text presentation on Mac and PC

Tags: html, macos, cross-platform, text-rendering

Can someone help me out on this one. I have a website which was developed on a Mac. When viewing certain text in "verdana" on the Mac all looks great, but on the PC the text is very fine and thin on all browsers. Other text with bold and larger size seems to present the same on both PC and Mac. Is there a simple way I can improve the browsers text representation on the PC.

Answer (score 3):

The two operating systems have different text rendering algorithms. The contrast is most drastic on thin letters, where Windows mangles the letterforms slightly but makes them look very crisp, while the Mac causes thin text to look smudged but preserves the shape better. This is not in your control as a Web developer.

Comment: This is what I believe, but there must be a workaround of some sort.

Comment: The only font that looks similar on both platforms is Comic Sans. Unfortunately the font is not suited for my use. One day someone will develop a font that looks the same on both platforms.

Comment: @MDM: The only workaround to the fact that operating systems intentionally make fonts look different is not to use fonts. Stick all your text in images. This is vastly worse, but it is the only way to bypass the system font rendering routines.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering always depends on system. Like on windows, if the user has setup [clear type fonts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306527), he will be having a much better experience.

**Some useful information**

that may help take decision on improving font families for different systems

- [Common fonts on all systems](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-CombinedResults.shtml)
- [Some good information on various fonts](http://www.angelfire.com/al4/rcollins/style/fonts.html) that work on different systems and are best rendered at certain sizes.
  -

**codestyle.org determined best fonts via survey.**

See that verdana comes out lower in both case.

For Windows:

```
Tahoma – 99.81%
Microsoft Sans Serif – 99.71%
Courier New – 99.66%
Verdana – 99.66%
Times New Roman – 99.37%
Arial – 99.32%
Trebuchet MS – 99.27%
Comic Sans MS – 99.13%
Lucida Console – 99.13%
Georgia – 98.94%
Impact – 98.89%
Lucida Sans Unicode – 98.65%
Palatino Linotype – 98.65%
Arial Black – 98.55%
Franklin Gothic Medium 97.96%
```

For Mac:

```
Helvetica – 100%
Lucida Grande – 100%
Geneva – 99.43%
Monaco – 99.43%
Courier – 98.85%
Times – 97.70%
Arial – 97.41%
Verdana – 97.41%
Georgia – 95.11%
Helvetica Neue – 95.11%
Trebuchet MS – 94.54%
Times New Roman – 94.25%
```

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful info. www.codestyle.org was very informative. Why can't both manufacturers get together and come up with a common font That looks the same. The only one that looks similar in both platforms Mac and PC (sorry Linux could not check, but you are usually good) is Comic Sans MS which I think is unsuitable for my use. I will try with a CSS workaround.

Comment: @MDM : Couldn't get your second comment :)